# Accessing parent helper in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I often find myself dividing my work into templates that still could use the same helpers.

So, say I have this template structure:

```
<template name="MainTemplate">
  <div>{{> FirstTemplate}}</div>
  <div>{{> SecondTemplate}}</div>
  <div>{{> ThirdTemplate}}</div>
  <div>{{> FourthTemplate}}</div>
</template>
```

Now each of these templates wants to use the same helper, let's call it `dataHelper`:

```
Template.MainTemplate.helpers({
  dataHelper: function() {
    //do some stuff
    return result
  }
})
```

Sadly, this helper can't be accessed in template first through fourth by simply typing `{{dataHelper}}` like how events work.

My solution has been to create a global helper instead, but that seems a tad overkill, especially since I have a few pages that don't care about these helpers at all. Another solution is to create four separate helpers but, hey, DRY.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: Do you actually need to reuse a function (e.g. `formatDate`) and call it with new data, or do you simply need some shared context? I think this would be easier to answer with a more concrete example in the question.

Comment: @DavidWeldon No data involved, just accessing parent helper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't an obvious way to do this in the current version of meteor. One solution is for the child template to "inherit" the helpers from the parent. You can do this pretty easily using [meteor-template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension). Here's an example:

### html

```
<body>
  {{> parent}}
</body>

<template name="parent">
  <h1>parent</h1>
  {{> child}}
</template>

<template name="child">
  <h2>child</h2>
  <p>{{saySomething}}</p>
</template>
```

### js

```
Template.parent.helpers({
  saySomething: function() {
    return Random.choice(['hello', 'dude!', 'i know right?']);
  }
});

Template.child.inheritsHelpersFrom('parent');
```

The template `child` inherits all of its parent's helpers so it has direct access to `saySomething`.

This technique has two drawbacks:

- you have to specify the `inheritsHelpersFrom` relationship
- **all** of the parent's helpers are inherited

Comment: Will it be re-initialized then?

Answer (score 5):

You can access your parent helpers using either a notation like `{{yourParentHelper ..}}` with two dots. [Have a look here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/) for more informations (end of the article)

You can also access parent data context in javascript like that:

```
var parent_data = Template.parentData();
```

By the way, you can add a parameter to reach the third parent, for instance:

```
var parent_data = Template.parentData(3);
```

Comment: This notation stalls my entire page and nothing will load.

Comment: pls post more details in your question. AFAIK that should work. Did you try to build a similar helper than the one you want to reach and use `Template.parentData();` to access what in the parent context?

Comment: All I did was try it out. I included a helper in a parent template that simply writes something to the console and then tried to access it using `{{dataHelper ..}}`. Stalled big time.

Comment: I cant test it at the moment. It might not work anymore. Will you try with javascript?

Comment: With javascript? What does that mean?

Comment: You make an additional helper and you provide the same kind of data than the parent helper you want to reach, using the `Template.parentData();` function

Comment: Don't know what that means, but I made this: http://meteorpad.com/pad/aSTnRGfN9WXPxNZTj/Leaderboard

Comment: Notice how it stalls and all I did was try to access a parent helper inside `leaderboard`.

Answer (score 2):

The double dot notation seems to work best within `{{#each}}` loops, and I'm not having any luck within actual child templates. One option would be to use `{{#with}}`, although that limits you to basically one helper. e.g.:

```
<template name="parent">
  {{#with dataHelper}}
    {{> first}}
    {{> second}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

This will set the data context of the child helpers to `dataHelper`, and you can access them with `{{this}}` inside the template. I suppose you could make `dataHelper` an object and then pass in multiple pieces of data that way.