# How to share meteor js helper functions to all children templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Meteor version 1.5 with Blaze and Iron Router.

I have a parent template that will contain several children templates. The children will all have javascript functions in common, so I want to place these 'helpers' on the parent to be available to all of the children template. So, it would be an event on a child that might call several helpers that should be shared everywhere.

```
<template name="to-do-list">
  {{#each to-dos}}
   {{>to-do-magic-buttons}}
   {{>to-do-magic-slider}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The to-do-list.js file imports the to-do-magic-buttons.js and to-do-magic-slider.js files at the top.  to-do-list.js looks like:

```
    let helpers = {
      printSomeThings: function(){
        console.log('some things');
      },
      upperCaseIt: function(text){
        return text.toUpperCase();
      }
    }

   Template.to-do-list.helpers(helpers);
```

or I have even tried to declare them via a function expression at the end of the to-do-list.js files.

When I try to call the parent functions from the child js files, the browser tells me that printSomeThings and upperCaseIt are not defined.

How can I share functions to all child functions from the parent?

Comment: Is using [global template helpers](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-global-template-helpers) an option for you? You could register/unregister them when the template is created/destroyed.

Comment: You may find what you want here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922695/accessing-parent-helper-in-meteor

Comment: See [global helpers](http://blazejs.org/guide/reusing-code.html#Global-Helpers) in the blaze docs.